# how to redirect to checkout click proceed to checkout from mini cart while customer is logout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, customer-login

My guest checkout is disable so while clicking to proceed to checkout from mini cart it shows a login popup.after login from this popup i want to redirect to checkout but it redirect to the same page first after login . Can any one help to redirect the site to checkout page after ajax login.

Comment: Then why you have kept guest checkout disable.

Comment: my requirement is quite like that i need to disable guest check out. But again need this while guest checkout is disable.

Answer (score 0):

Please preference for Magento\Customer\Controller\Ajax\Login

replace -

```
$response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($redirectRoute);
```

WITH

```
$response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('onestepcheckout'));
```

and Also add

```
public function __construct(
  ....,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 ) {
      ....
      $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
  }
```